# EC2 CentOS 5 SSL Cert Configuration

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, ssl

I purchased an SSL cert from GoDaddy and followed instructions 1 & 2 on this guide: 
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Https

When I paste my CSR into the GoDaddy console, it says "Domain name empty, can't retrieve subdomain." - Should I continue on with the steps 3 & 4 on that instruction page? I got the impression they were optional. Also, I don't know why the GoDaddy console says "subdomain" as I do not have a subdomain setup on the EC2 server, just a domain name I purchased from godaddy that I have assigned to it.

Any other advice is appreciated as I've never set up an SSL cert with an EC2 server like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating a CSR you need to put the domain name in the common name prompt. Follow the following instructions to generate your CSR:

1. Log in to your server's terminal (SSH).
2. At the prompt, type the following command:
3. `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domainname.key -out
   domainname.csr`
4. Replace domainname with the domain name you're securing. For
   example, if your domain name is wirehive.net, you would type
   wirehive.net.key and wirehive.net.csr.
5. Enter the requested information:

   Common Name: The fully-qualified domain name, or URL, you're
   securing. Do not include 'https://'.

   If you are requesting a Wildcard certificate, add an asterisk (*) to
   the left of the common name where you want the wildcard, for example
   *.coolexample.com. Organization: The legally-registered name for your business. If you are enrolling as an individual, enter the
   certificate requestor's name.

   Organization Unit: The department within your business, eg IT.

   City or Locality: Name full name of the city where your organization
   is located.

   State or Province: Full name of your county (Or state if you are
   American!).

   Country: The two-letter International Organization for
   Standardization (ISO) format country code for where your
   organization is legally registered. (eg GB)

   Leave the Passphrase field blank if you do not want to manually
   enter a password every time you start or reboot the web server.
6. Open the CSR in a text editor and copy all of the text.

Comment: Thank you, I think I was messing up the qualified name the whole time, because I included http:// ... you are not supposed to include that, you are only supposed to use this format: www.domain.com Thank you!

Comment: That would do it! No problem.